# Concurrent workflow not starting from PMCMD Command

Tags: concurrency, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a requirement to start workflow concurrently with multiple instances, all instances need to run in parallel. When I run an instance it is running and related param file is being picked up. But when I start another instance to run in parallel with previous instance, it is giving below Error.

"Start Workflow Advanced: ERROR: Workflow [wf_name]: Could not start execution of this workflow because the current run on this Integration Service has not completed yet."

I tried doing this using PMCMDcommand like below. It's starting without any param file and without instance name. But PMCMD log is showing the the workflow is started for the given instance successfully.

pmcmd startworkflow -sv 'INT_......' -d 'DOM_......' -u 'venkat' -p `MyPass....` -f 'MyFold...' -nowait -rin $inst_name $wf_name

This is working fine in our test environment. But not working in QA. Is there a configuration setting to avoid this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure the workflow is properly configured to allow multiple executions: the `Configure Concurrent Execution` has to be enabled and `Allow concurrent run...` needs to be correctly set. If you run with same instance name, the `Allow concurent run with same instance name` must be chosen. Otherwise, choose the `Allow concurent run only with unique instance name`, add the instance name and desired parameter file to the list below.

In your command I don't see the parameterfile, so I assume the latter should be the proper setup.

Comment: I have used "Allow concurrent run only with unique instance name" option and created instance names with praram files. That is correctly working in Dev environment. But not working in QA.

Comment: Have you checked if a previous run of the same instance is still running in qa

Comment: I'm not sure what is the value of $inst_name in your command. Please double check if it's not the same one - in such case it would behave exactly as you've described.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved by restarting the integration service. We did not restart integration service to fix this issue. But that resolved this issue. When we contacted informatica support for resolution, below KB link is provided by them. https://kb.informatica.com/solution/23/Pages/59/501120.aspx

Please find the thread I have opened in Informatica network.

https://network.informatica.com/thread/83540